# Checking if a user is already registered and confirmed in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I need to check if a user is already registered and confirmed by e-mail.

Now, I know that Laravel already checks if a user already exists.

All I need is to put something like this:

```
if($found_user->exists && $found_user->confirmed == 1) 
{
//do this
}else if($found_user->exists && $found_user->confirmed == 0)
{
//do that
}
```

I could easily do that in the `RegisterController`, in the function `create(array $data)` but I have the feeling that it is not the correct place to put the function, as it is called once it has been validated.

Is there a proper place to put it or should it stay in create?

Comment: which version you are using.

Comment: @404BrainNotFound Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to put it in the function.

```
create(array $data){
    $this->check_user_confirmation($data["email"])
...
}
```

While I know that there is a function somewhere that checks if the user already exists, and that it would be optimal to do the check there, it is probably part of the core of the application which I dislike to modify in any Framework.

If someone else has a better idea I am still open.

Comment: For validating the user is exist or not you can easily check in validator like `'email' => 'required|string|email|max:20|unique:users'`

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @404BrainNotFound as I said before, I need to see if the user exists AND if it is confirmed or not. If it is registered and confirmed, it will tell you that it already exists. If it is registered and not confirmed, it will tell you to check spam and send an email again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes)

You can attach `auth` middleware to routes you want to protect, or directly in the `__construct` of your controller

> Laravel ships with an auth middleware, which is defined at Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate

If you want your [own Auth middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) you can type the following

`php artisan make:middleware MyOwnAuth`

In that way you can check if the user is confirmed or not on the page you needs

Comment: I know about middleware. That is not the problem. If a user is registered and tries to register with the same e-mail, but that e-mail is not confirmed, it will tell you to check your spam box and send a new confirmation e-mail. If a user is registered and the e-mail is confirmed, it will simply say that the user already exists. This needs to be done some time after submitting the register form.

Comment: You can use that https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#manually-creating-validators and use `redirectTo` where a method who send mail again

Answer (score 0):

Better version of yours Laravel has middleware facility with it and basic concept of middleware is to do things like restrictions without passing the request to server just like a filter.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckConfirmedUser {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next ) {
        if ( $found_user->exists && $found_user->confirmed == 1 ) {
            //do this
        } else if ( $found_user->exists && $found_user->confirmed == 0 ) {
            //do that
        }

        return $next( $request );
    }
}
```

You need to query for `$found_user`